# Rest API SharePoint 2019 Endpoint for List Settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-rest-api, 2019

I am looking for a SharePoint 2013/2019 API endpoint to get access to List Settings, including Advanced Settings.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What exactly you want to change in list settings?

Comment: Hi Ganesh! I want to experiment setting up an Alteryx workflow that would change all the settings that I normally do manually. Such as, managing content types, turning off attachments, turn on versioning, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links to SharePoint REST API endpoints/documentations which might help you:

1. [Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service)
2. [Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)
3. [SharePoint REST API reference and samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/jj860569(v=office.15))
4. [Lists and list items REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531433(v=office.15)) - `EnableVersioning` for versioning and `EnableAttachments` for attachments
5. [List Fields REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182(v=office.15))

Endpoint for list content types is:

```
https://<site url>/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('List Name')/ContentTypes
```

OR

```
https://<site url>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'482e418a-0900-414b-8902-02248c2e44e8')/ContentTypes
```